# I install a module in my personal computer and it works however when I install it in my work computer it does not. (Odoo 14)

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-14

I have a problem and I do not know why. I created a module `mrp_custom` and I installed it on my laptop and works perfectly. However, when I install on my work computer, it doesn't work and gives an error. Here I show my model, the inherited view and the error.

P.D.: On my laptop it works perfectly and on the other computer it does not.

**Model**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api


class MRPProductsName(models.Model): # FUNCION DEL CAMPO PARA PRODUCTOS SOLO
    _inherit = 'mrp.production'

    products_name = fields.Char('Producto', related="product_id.product_tmpl_id.name")
```

**Inherited View**

```xml
<!-- INHERITED VIEW PRODUCTION -->

<record id="view_production_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">view.production.form.inherit</field>
    <field name="model">mrp.production</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_production_tree_view"/>
    <field name="arch" type="html">
        <xpath expr="//field[@name='product_id']" position="after">
            <field name="products_name" optional="show"/>                  
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

**Error**

> File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 14\server\odoo\models.py", line 4983, in ensure_one
> raise ValueError("Expected singleton: %s" % self) Exception
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files\Odoo
> 14\server\odoo\http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
> return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "C:\Program Files\Odoo 14\server\odoo\http.py", line 315, in
> _handle_exception
> raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause ValueError: Expected singleton: product.template(2582, 2657, 2624)

Comment: Why are there both odoo-9 and odoo-14 tags in here?

Comment: I wrote it because the problem is compatible with all version. Is it wrong? I am sorry If It is wrong, I new in this and I will go learning Holydragon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking in this error: `Expected singleton: product.template(2582, 2657, 2624)`. There can be multiple product_template related to single product_product. Please make sure there only one product_template related to one product_product!

Comment: Randy, this is because the product has attributes and I want to separate them in product name by one side and the other attributes

Comment: @MauriSadaniowski So why dont you create new field on product_product to save its own name instead of create many product_template relate to it ?